# ipad programs for replacing paper scripts?

Tags: ipad, script, software

anyone know a good ipad based script reader?

Ideally it would be able to open a wide variety of formats (.doc, docx, excel, pdf, etc) and would be able to allow the talent to scribble, highlight, make notes etc.  stylus use would be ok.

I'd also like navigation to be obvious and simple, so that there would be little to no instruction to people unfamiliar to whatever program it is.

any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't fit all your criteria, but I use iAnnotatePDF. I can import a script in pdf format and write on it, drop markers and notes, highlight passages. I don't think it's completely ideal but it does work fairly well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely look at GoodReader for iPad. It's a fantastic app for reading most major formats, including doc and pdf. Moreover, it allows you to circle, highlight, annotate and draw on the documents on a separate layer, and in most standard colors. I work a lot in theater and use it all of the time to take sound notes during tech rehearsals.

It costs $4.99, but it's worth it.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader-for-ipad/id363448914?mt=8

~Matt

Answer (score 1):

Use air display to use your ipad as a third monitor and just run word/excel or whatever on your pc/mac.

http://avatron.com/apps/air-display

Comment: Extra tip: This is great for guerilla foley. You can have a QT movie on the iPad for the performer on the same machine running your audio session.

Answer (score 0):

I immediately thought about [Docs To Go](http://www.dataviz.com/DTG_iphone.html). It fits most of your criterias. Don't know about scribbling though.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something that can be edited and changed on the fly, look into [Fountain](http://fountain.io/). Not great for all on set, oriented towards writing, but it uses markdown-style annotations to store scripts in raw text for maximum compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Currently testing iAnnotate and GoodReader with a view to going paperless in the ADR theatre; will keep you posted on my findings, Rene.